# KotlinTest`s BehaviorSpec "No runnable methods" with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

I wrote the following test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class KotlinTest : BehaviorSpec() {
    init {
        given("a stack") {
            val stack = Stack<String>()
            `when`("an item is pushed") {
                stack.push("kotlin")
                then("the stack should not be empty") {
                    stack.isEmpty() shouldBe true
                }
            }
            `when`("the stack is popped") {
                stack.pop()
                then("it should be empty") {
                    stack.isEmpty() shouldBe false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run it, I have the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:138)
```

I know that the problem is that I am trying to run a test written with KotlinTest with Spring, but how can I do it? What runner should I use?

**The example test doesn't need spring, this was just a simple example that I wrote to isolate the problem**

Comment: could you try `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class.java` instead of `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote your test in the constructor. Tests should be written in functions with `@Test` annotation. Your code is more less the equivalent of:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public final class JavaTest extends BehaviorSpec {

    public JavaTest() {
         // given stack, when item is pushed, ...
    }
}
```

What you want instead is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public final class JavaTest extends BehaviorSpec {

    @Test
    public void testName() {
        // given stack, when item is pushed, ...
    }
}
```

To achieve this you need to use `fun` keyword to define a function. The result should look more less like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class KotlinTest : BehaviorSpec() {

    @Test fun testName() {
        given stack, when item is pushed, ...
    }
}
```

Comment: KotlinTest tests are structured this way by design.

Comment: @Sam I agree with you, but I think that I we need a custom runner. For now, the answer from Mibac is the best option we have.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)`. That's overriding the KotlinTest runner, which is `KTestJUnitRunner`. In order for your KotlinTest tests to be picked up, you need to use the correct test runner.

Removing your `RunWith` annotation should fix the problem. Then the test runner will be inherited from the `BehaviorSpec` superclass as intended.

Comment: If I use KTestJUnitRunner, spring don't inject my dependencies.

Comment: You can use `@SpringClassRule` and `@SpringMethodRule` to enable the spring test context features while not using the spring test runner.

Comment: the '@SpringMethodRule' can't be defined in the init method. I couldn't find the '@SpringClassRule' annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the logic of the test is the opposite it should be:
first   `stack.isEmpty() shouldBe false`
second  `stack.isEmpty() shouldBe true`
When I run the test with gradle (and without @RunWith) with kotlintest I
cannot fix the problem in any way: `nosense java.util.EmptyStackException`
and `java.lang.AssertionError`

```
        When("an item is pushed") {
            stack.push("kotlin")
            Then("the stack should not be empty") { 
                  stack.isEmpty() shouldBe false
                //stack.empty() shouldBe false
                //stack.size shouldBe gt(0)

            }
        }
        When("the stack is popped") {
            stack.pop()
            Then("it should be empty") {
                stack.isEmpty() shouldBe true        
            }
        }
```

I know this is not the question you ask, but your logic seems reversed.
I cannot fix with gradle and kotlintest.